# Copee Pastee alternative?

Tags: add-on, 2.7.0

Just wondering whether anyone has come across a replacement / fix for Copee Pastee which no longer appears to work in EE 2.7.

Any insights would be most welcome.

Cheers

Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jim Pannell and I worked out a solution, making Copee Pastee work in EE 2.7.

Add the following to /system/expressionengine/third_party/copee_pastee/ft.copee_pastee.php, at line 77.

```
public function display_field($data)
{
    //nothing
}
```